# How to create bounder for GMSMarker

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, geofencing

I have two `GMSMarker` were one of the is moving and the other is not and I want to create something smilier to `geofencing` where if the moving marker entered or left the bounder of the unmoving one I will able to do some actions,

I found an geofencing APIs by google but it is for android only, is there a way to do this in swift?

can the `GMSCircle` be used to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Please check below code. Here is have created the area manually by setting the lat, long for each point. You can set your region by passing the lat,long in create area function and draw a circular region. Then make use of CLLocationManager delegate to monitor the marker.

```
var selectedPlace: GMSPlace? 
let rect = GMSMutablePath()


func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
    print("Place name: \(place.name)")
    showPin(myPlace: place)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func showPin(myPlace: GMSPlace){
    mapView.clear()
    createArea()
    selectedPlace = myPlace
    print((selectedPlace?.coordinate)!)
    if(GMSGeometryContainsLocation((selectedPlace?.coordinate)!, rect, true)) 
{
print("YES: you are in this polygon.")

    }else{
        print("You do not appear to be in this polygon.")
    }


func createArea(){
    // Create a rectangular path

    rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 18.882534, longitude: 72.801590))//Fort
    rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 19.492122, longitude: 72.737045))//Virar
    rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 19.476586, longitude: 73.096848))//Virar Right
    rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 19.271893, longitude: 73.127060))//Kalyan
    rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 19.186313, longitude: 73.243790))//Badlapur
    //rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 18.811052, longitude: 73.547287))//Karjat
    rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 18.966973, longitude: 73.107834))//Panvel
    rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 19.021510, longitude: 72.975998))//Vashi
    rect.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 18.882534, longitude: 72.801590))//Mumbai

    // Create the polygon, and assign it to the map.
    let polygon = GMSPolygon(path: rect)
    polygon.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.25, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.05);
    polygon.strokeColor = .black
    polygon.strokeWidth = 2
    polygon.map = mapView
}
```

//CLLocationManager Delegates

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didStartMonitoringFor region: CLRegion){
    print("Start Monitoring Region")

}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, for region: CLRegion){
    print("Determine Region State")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion){
    print("Entered Monitoring Region")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion){
    print("Exited Monitoring Region")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, monitoringDidFailFor region: CLRegion?, withError error: Error){
    print("Failed Monitoring Region")
}
```

Comment: if I use CLLocationManager I will tracking the user location right? if so , then that not want I want the user location in irrelevant in my case

Comment: If you are not using CLLocation manager.. you can use showPin function to draw your marker and check if marker is in the rect. You can draw rect using createArea() function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CLRegion?

create one region at not moving marker with radius and call its delegate method for entering and exiting the moving marker.

and for CLLocationManger you can start monitoring for region.

Comment: same thing I am not use the CLLocationManger user location is irrelevant I have GMSmarker that I want to track